# Feed The Beast pack won't start

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

My Feed the Beast mod pack crashes as soon as it finishes the "FTB" start page. I am on Mac OSX Lion, running Apple Java 6. It gives me no warning, it just closes randomly, like it can't open the thread maybe?

Here's a video demonstrating the crash, first using Java 7, then using Java 6:

Comment: p.s. I am using the fix for apple java six

Comment: Which FTB modpack (there are several, such as Unleashed, Ultimate, etc.), and which version number of that modpack?

Comment: I believe that it is the same with all, but the first and mist recent one

Comment: Are you sure? Unleashed and Unhinged are very similarly named. Could you please check and put the specific details in the question? There's no point in getting an answer for the wrong pack and version. If you get this crash with both Unleashed and Unhinged, that is also useful information to put in the question since it narrows down the possibilities.

Comment: unleashed is the version, but I have not tried unhinged. Doing that now. P.S. What does sethbling use for his videos on FTB

Comment: unhinged crashes too

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/GXgx9FAd)Right here is pastebin[/link]

Comment: OOH. It's not FTB crashing, it's the FTB *Launcher* crashing.

Comment: Do you have any non-FTB mods installed? Such as OptiFine?

Comment: no I do not. Should I delete the ftb home filde and regenerate. Youtube prossing

Comment: No, it was just a slim chance that the launcher was choking on an external mod, according to a thread I found while searching for the CGContext errors in the pastebin. If you don't have any, that's not the problem then.

Comment: it is yelling at us. P.S. LINK(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rNt_LCdF94&feature=youtube_gdata_player) Crud again with modified bulitun board markup.

Comment: should I JUST MOD IT MYSELF? crazy caps loc on non mac keybord

Comment: Judging by the video, it's crashing during FML setup. There should be a file named `ForgeModLoader-client-0.log` in the .minecraft folder inside wherever you have FTB installed. Can you put that in a pastebin for us?

Comment: here: http://pastebin.com/i4CyWBYK

Comment: This is when I did it manually with just forge: http://pastebin.com/ds9jx0K5

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "with just forge" in the second comment. The pastebin in the first comment ends prematurely as soon as LWJGL (the graphics/sound library) is loaded. That plus the CGContext errors seems to say it's a problem with the version of LWJGL that FTB is using being incompatible with Mac OS's OpenGL libraries. (The error also appears to be fixed by updating to Mountain Lion, which further supports the idea it's a problem with libraries.) [Try updating LWJGL using the manual instructions here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1625325-how-to-update-lwjgl/).

Comment: Be sure to update LWJGL in FTB's copy of Minecraft though, not the default copy of Minecraft.

Comment: I think that that forge virstion is broken

Comment: do I put the contents where EXACTLY?

Comment: I don't know, since I don't know where you have FTB installed. Check the launcher's **Options** tab and look at the **Install folder** setting to find FTB's minecraft folder.

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks. Do you know if this is a windows problem too? I am thinking of making a ftb server, after I get an 8 gig ram card for mac. P.S. Thank you for editing the post to show the video. Does that format work well for this site?

Comment: Updating LWJGL did the trick? Excellent! No, it sounds like this is a problem only with Mac OS X Lion. Updating to Mountain Lion is supposed to fix it too.

Comment: Video in question is dead.

Comment: @pppery Still, it has an accepted answer, and there is more info in the comments. Is the 'we don't answer questions about modded Minecraft' rule applied retroactively?

Comment: @Joachim Yes, that is why I flagged the question. I have a strong belief that questions that are now off-topic should be closed as off-topic, even if they were on-topic when they were asked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this a request for tech support for modded minecraft, and the video with the details is a dead link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update LWJGL in FTB's copy of Minecraft, not the default copy of Minecraft.

Comment: This is a copy of the already existing answer in the comments.  If SevenSidedDie posts the same answer, I will delete this one.

Comment: I am the generous type and I just wanted him to earn reputation for it

Comment: Plus, you have to admit, people do not want to search through 30 comments just to find the answer.